# amazon mws submit feed

Tags: curl, amazon-mws

I am attempting a go at updating quantities using the SubmitFeed action.  Does anyone have experience with this?  The error I am receiving is: 'Either Action or Operation query parameter must be present', but I do have 'Action=SubmitFeed' in the query string.

I have written four other functions (RequestReport, GetReportRequestList, GetReport, & GetFeedSubmissionList) that work perfectly.  I imagine I am missing some cURL configuration options in order to post a file.

cURL options:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-MD5: '. $md5,
    'Transfer-Encoding: chunked',
)),
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD => true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, implode('&', $url_parts));
```

Can anyone assist?  Thank you.

Comment: Hi, can you please share all your parameters, what you have here is not enough to help.

Comment: What parameters?  These are all I had for cURL.  This may be of help to others: lookup AMTU.  This is a much simpler method of submitting feeds.  The AMTU worked after a few moments of writing code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do a `SubmitFeed` call, you will have to use `Content-Type: text/xml` and use your XML feed as CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. Your other option fields will have to go into the URL, as if this was a `GET`:

```
$ch = curl_init($url_with_fields);                   <-- change 1
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml',                        <-- change 2
    'Content-MD5: '. $md5,
    'Transfer-Encoding: chunked',
)),
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD => true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmldata);      <-- change 3
```

Note that this type of call *also* works for RequestReport, GetReportRequestList, GetReport, & GetFeedSubmissionList: just leave $xmldata empty in those cases.

Comment: you do not need to set CURLOPT_UPLOAD as it changes the method to PUT. All you need is POST

Comment: @debianek True. I tried to make minimal changes to his code and didn't notice the CURLOPT_UPLOAD in there. I think it should still work, though, but haven't actually tried.